# How do I get write permissions on a samba share?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, samba

I am trying to get write access to my Minecraft server with my windows 10 machine. Right now I only have read access. I am using a Ubuntu 22.04 server. Here is my current smb.conf:

```
[minecraft-files]
        comment = user Samba Share
        path = /home/user/mc-files
        read only = no
        browsable = yes
        writeable = yes
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
```

permissions (Note that my username is 'user')

`drwx------  11 user user 4096 Jun 18 06:31 mc-files`

Output of `testparm -s`:

```
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:                                                                                                                                                             * %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[server-storage]
        comment = user Samba Share
        path = /home/user/server-storage
        read only = No


[minecraft-files]
        comment = user Samba Share
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
        path = /home/user/mc-files
        read only = No
```

Output of `ls -al /home/user/mc-files`:

```
drwxrwxrwx+  9 user user 4096 Jun 18 07:03 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001    2 Jun 18 06:33 banned-ips.json
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001    2 Jun 18 06:33 banned-players.json
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001  697 Jun 18 06:33 bukkit.yml
drwxr-xr-x   2 9001 9001 4096 Jun 13 01:36 cache
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001  104 Jun 18 06:33 commands.yml
drwxr-xr-x   2 9001 9001 4096 Jun 18 06:33 config
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001  158 Jun 13 01:36 eula.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 9001 9001    0 Jun 13 01:36 help.yml
drwxr-xr-x  11 9001 9001 4096 Jun 13 01:36 libraries
drwxr-xr-x   2 9001 9001 4096 Jun 18 06:32 logs
```

(There's more, but this should be enough)

I set the permissions to 700 because I set them to 777 before, until I found out that 777 is bad.

Any permissions or something in the config files that I need to change to get read and write access on windows 10?

I have looked at similar questions to this one, but those are very old questions and in different versions of ubuntu.

Comment: Please read about permissions on linux (for example: [Linux file permissions explained](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-file-permissions-explained)).  After reading you will know why this: "**I set the permissions to 700 because I set them to 777 before, until I found out that 777 is bad.**" is the cause of this behaviour.

Comment: Not enough information provided to answer the question. Please edit your original post and add the output of the following commands: `testparm -s` and `ls -al /home/user/mc-files` If you have a lot of files in mc-files the first 10 lines or so from the ls -al command is enough.

Comment: Did you add `user` as a Samba user? Your Samba share doesn’t list any valid users. If you want to restrict access to valid users only, then add `valid users = user`. Finally, the Unix permissions on the filesystem need to allow read/write access for that user. Read more about Samba Users and Security [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html).

Comment: uid = 9001? Is this in a Docker container? You might want to look at the last comment here and the link within it to see if this applies: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/cant-use-samba-on-a-docker-folder.3761764/